# SSRS Matrix Report With Custom Fields

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to create a waterfall style report using the matrix style in SSRS with an unknown number of columns and they are all named m1, m2, m3, m4, etc.  Each m value contains the total paid for that time frame.  How can I specify the custom field name in the matrix.

```
                                    (Column_Group)
| Date Arrived | Cost   | Payment | [ArriveDate]  |
|---------------------------------|---------------|
| [ArriveDate] | [Cost] | [Pay]   | [m1]          |
```

Example of what I'd like to see:

```
| Date Arrived | Cost   | Payment | 2018/05      | 2018/06      |
|---------------------------------|-----------------------------|
| 2018/05      | $200   | $100    | $25.00       | $75.00       |
| 2018/06      | $400   | $200    | $100.00      | $100.00      |
```

SQL Dataset Sent To Report:

```
| ArriveDate | Cost | Pay | m1  | m2  |
---------------------------------------
| 2018/05    | 200  | 100 | 25  | 50  |
| 2018/06    | 400  | 200 | 100 | 100 |
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your data?

Comment: Updated per your request.

Comment: can you show what your actual dataset looks like rather than what the layout is / the way you want it displayed.. need to see how [m1] translates to 2018/05 for example..

Comment: That is the actual dataset.  m1 header is first field of arrive date, m2 is second field of arrive date.  Arrive date is populated both on row and columns.  By the row you can see how much was spent and how much was paid, the columns show when the money was paid.